# System.ArgumentNullException using botframework vision api

Tags: c#, botframework

```
InternalServerError
{

  "message": "An error has occurred.",

  "exceptionMessage": "Value cannot be null.\r\nParameter name: source",

  "exceptionType": "System.ArgumentNullException",

  "stackTrace": "   at System.Linq.Enumerable.Any[TSource](IEnumerable`1 source)\r\n   
at Bot0.MessagesController.<Post>d__0.MoveNext() in D:\\~\\MessagesController.cs:line 51\r\n--- 
End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---\r\n   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)\r\n   
at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()\r\n--- ~

}
```

I'm getting the error message above when I try to test my bot online @ dev.botframework.com.

Below is some of the related codes in 'MessagesController.cs' that is giving me the error message, line 51 starts with the if statement, my bot test just fine without the block of code that starts at line 51:

```
ConnectorClient connector = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
const string visionApiKey = "mykey123";

//Vision SDK classes
VisionServiceClient visionClient = new VisionServiceClient(visionApiKey);
VisualFeature[] visualFeatures = new VisualFeature[] {
                            VisualFeature.Adult, //recognize adult content
                            VisualFeature.Categories, //recognize image features
                            VisualFeature.Description //generate image caption
                            };
AnalysisResult analysisResult = null;

ConnectorClient connector1 = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl));
const string emotionApiKey = "mykey456";

//Emotion SDK objects that take care of the hard work
EmotionServiceClient emotionServiceClient = new EmotionServiceClient(emotionApiKey);
Emotion[] emotionResult = null;

if (activity.Attachments.Any() && activity.Attachments.First().ContentType.Contains("image"))
     {
            //stores image url (parsed from attachment or message)
            string uploadedImageUrl = activity.Attachments.First().ContentUrl; ;
            uploadedImageUrl = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uploadedImageUrl.Substring(uploadedImageUrl.IndexOf("file=") + 5));

            using (Stream imageFileStream = File.OpenRead(uploadedImageUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    analysisResult = await visionClient.AnalyzeImageAsync(imageFileStream, visualFeatures);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    analysisResult = null; //on error, reset analysis result to null
                }
            }

            using (Stream imageFileStream1 = File.OpenRead(uploadedImageUrl))
            {
                try
                {
                    emotionResult = await emotionServiceClient.RecognizeAsync(imageFileStream1);
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    emotionResult = null; //on error, reset analysis result to null
                }
            }
    }
```

I've tried debugging it but it doesn't give me an error message locally on my PC, only when I am testing it online. I do not know why I am getting this error message.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on exception message and sample code it looks like `activity.Attachments` is `null` when trying to call the `.Any()` extension method. Check to make sure `activity.Attachments` is not `null` before trying to access it

```
if (activity.Attachments != null && 
    activity.Attachments.Any() && 
    activity.Attachments.First().ContentType.Contains("image")) {
    //...
}
```

every `object.Something` has the potential to raise a NRE so you should take that into consideration when making those calls.

Comment: I wonder why that error message doesn't show up locally? Anyway, thank you!